# API endpoint with graphql endpoint says to embed sandbox on website

Tags: graphql, azure-functions

I have created a GraphQL API endpoint which when run on graphiql server says to embed sandbox on website. I dont have any frontend app created, what I have is just an api which was created on Azure functions locally with apollo-server-functions and typescript as the language. I dont see any errors when starting the api in the console. Below is the simple code I wrote to test the api -

```
    import { ApolloServer, gql } from "apollo-server-azure-functions"
    
    const typeDefs = gql`
        type Query {
            graphQlOnAzure: String!
        }
    `
    
    const resolvers = {
        Query: {
            graphQlOnAzure() {
                return "GraphQL on Azure!";
            }
        }
    }
    
    const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers})
    export default server.createHandler({ cors: {
        origin: 'http://localhost:7071',
        credentials: true
} });
```

And this is the error I get when clicking on the api link -
[image]

I have read adding CORS to the request would fix the issue but that did not. Any help is appreciated, digging into azure functions and graphql for the first time.

Comment: Is your graphql server running at `localhost:7071/api/graphql` ?

Comment: Yes @MichelFloyd

Comment: Try `query myQuery { graphQlOnAzure }`

Comment: @MichelFloyd I don’t get intellisense when I try the above query. It says something about the cord.

Comment: Does anybody have a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding "options" to the list of methods on function.json file fixed the issue for me.

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post",
        "options"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    }
  ],
  "scriptFile": "../dist/graphql/index.js"
}
```